# ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server: mysqld got signal 11 ;

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

when I install mysql-server-8.0 ver. 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 armhf on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on Raspberrypi4 (8GB ram) the result is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 115148 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
(Reading database ... 115348 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
2023-05-09T13:38:04Z UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=f16c68f8f63a58e9eabfa0c5f251618a2ffed724
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x2d) [0x1bbfad2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x253) [0x1066b58]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x71) [0x1066c72]
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(+0x27530) [0xb65f6530]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(memory::Aligned_atomic<long>::Aligned_atomic()+0x4d) [0x19417e6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Delegate::Delegate(unsigned int)+0x39) [0x1941a3e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(delegates_init()+0x37) [0x1941b80]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9fb69c) [0xebf69c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysqld_main(int, char**)+0x1f73) [0xec5d08]
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x97) [0xb65e65a4]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```